# $wpdb->insert is not respacting unique fields

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have been creating Wordpress plugin for a while. This is example of mysql table:

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $table_name  (
    id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    email       VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT NULL,
    telephone   VARCHAR(15) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(id),
    UNIQUE (email, telephone)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='WP plugin sesa_players db' AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
";
```

Email should be unique, right? phpMyAdmin says it it.

This is wordpress code that inserts data into that table:

```
$err = $wpdb->insert($wpdb->prefix.$table_name, $data, $format);
var_dump($err);
```

It works, even more than it should. Assume email is m@m.com. First insert goes well. Second try fails because of duplicate entry as it should. var_dump is false.
BUT if I refresh wp page, third try with same email passes flawlessly, var_dump 1. Any repeated wp refresh opens db for duplicate entry.
Why? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: No. Email is only unique in combination with telephone.

Comment: Aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa! Be quick, post it as an answer with solution to close this question.

Comment: Sorry, I was writing my answer while @Strawberry was posting a comment. +1 for his comment.

Comment: Thank you both :) +1 to Strawberry because I can only accept answer as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `email` is not `UNIQUE` here. Pair of `email` and `telephone` is `UNIQUE` in your table definition.

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $table_name  (
    id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    email       VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT NULL,
    telephone   VARCHAR(15) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(id),
    UNIQUE (email),
    UNIQUE (telephone)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='WP plugin sesa_players db' AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
";
```

Probably this is what you want.